# How to delcare and implement interface with constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that has type constraints:

```
public class DataManager<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : LogRecord, new()
{
    public TEntity GetRecord()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It has a derived class which uses ServerLogRecord derived LogRecord as TEntity:

```
public class ServerDataManager : DataManager<ServerLogRecord>
{
}
```

I want to abstract DataManager's public functions into an interface, so I can make it unittestable and decouple the implementation with client code, and because the public function returns TEntity, so I have to put the type constraints in interface:

```
public interface IDataManager<out TEntity> where TEntity : LogRecord, new()
{
    TEntity GetRecord();
}
```

Then I have a question, how should I declare my implantation class to keep it generic? I tried this solution suggested:

```
public class DataManager<TEntity> : IDataManager<TEntity>, IDisposable
```

However I got this error:

```
error CS0314: The type 'TEntity' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'IDataManager<TEntity>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TEntity' to 'LogRecord'.
```

but reapply constraints works:

```
public class DataManager<TEntity> : IDataManager<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : LogRecord, new()
```

So is "rewriting type constraints in implementation class" the only way to keep DataManager generic?

Comment: Don't you already have a class? first sentence.

Comment: If `DataManager` is non generic as it looks, then it shall directly use the `IDataManager<Type>`, where Type shall adhere to all the constraints defined by the interface, in case `DataManager` is also a generic like `DataManager<T>`, then you need to reapply the constraints again

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what was asked, Just have the class implement  the interface

```
public class DataManager<TEntity> : IDataManager<TEntity>, IDisposable { ... }
```

If the intention is not to have the implementation as a generic as well and you have you entity then

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager<MyClass>, IDisposable { ... }
```

Provided `MyClass` satisfies the constraint.

Comment: Constraints needn't be defined again in the class, they shall flow from the interface itself

Comment: @MrinalKamboj No, they do not.

Comment: Not every other implementation of the interface is necessarily disposable, so unless there's some reason why it's important that all implementors of the interface would need to be disposable, then no, the interface *shouldn't* extend `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Servy Ok i missed out for a Generic class, they need to be defined but not for a Non generic class, as the following code suggests.

`public interface ITest<T> where T : new() { T Method1(); }`

`public class A : ITest<B>{public B Method1() { return new B();}}`

`public class B{ }`

Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Sure, if you have no generic type you don't need to apply any generic constraints on it.  In fact, if you have no generic type you *can't* apply any generic constraints to it, because of course you have no generic type to apply constraints *to*.  But if you *do* have a generic type (as the OP *does* have), then you *do* need the constraints.

Comment: @Servy OP's `DataManager` class is non generic, in the edited question

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The class is incomplete; we have no idea what it's supposed to be.  Of course, if you want to argue that the class shouldn't be generic, then you could say *that*.  It would at least result in code with a shot at compiling if you make the class not generic, but just saying the *constraints* should be removed is nonsensical.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I need to keep DataManager generic. I tried your first solution, but got this error:  error CS0314: The type 'TEntity' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'IDataManager<TEntity>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TEntity' to 'LogRecord'.

Answer (score 0):

when implementing interfaces, you are expected to provide the real classes which are going to be used 
in the implementation not generic types because most times, you would not be calling the implementation but 
the interfaces.
consider this code

```
//Where K is key
//where T is a generic entity which may be a programming language
public interface ICoder<K, T>
{

Task Program();
Task LearnNewLanguage(T Language);
K GetCoderId();
}
```

and your implementation

```
public class CoderImplementation<TDbContext> : ICoder<string, ProgrammingLanguage> where TDbContext : DbContext
{

private readonly TDbContext _edu;
public CoderImplemtation(TDbContext edu)
{
_edu = edu;
}
public Task Program()
{
...start programming by 12 to 6
}

public Task LearnNewLanguage(string Name)
{
_edu.AddLanguage(Name);
}
}
```

By telling it that `TDbContext` is of type `DbContext` you can be able to access methods which a `DbContext` exposes
even though that `DbContext` is not known